What are default values of titleX (y axis) and titleY (x axis) in VegaLite
I am trying to create chart in VegaLite.
In chart I am trying to titleX of axis vai params but i am facing a issue if i did not able to provide default value of titleX (means what value is used by vegaLite when titleX is not define) ,i am trying to provide same  vai param for SecondYAxisTitleOffset .Editor link

I trying to set same value vai param that is default value of titleX properties of y axis , if end user wants to set position otherwise work with default as vega work , so basically what is default value
